# Node.js auth0 login get id_token

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new at Nodejs and auth0.I'm Sorry If my question is stupid. I want extraParams.id_token save into session(now I have user in req.user and i want something like user.id_toke). Now I get this error : Cannot set property 'id_token' of undefined.

```
    // Configure Passport to use Auth0
    var strategy = new Auth0Strategy({
        domain:       process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        clientID:     process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL:  'http://localhost:3004/callback'
    }, function(req,accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) {
        // accessToken is the token to call Auth0 API (not needed in the most cases)
        // extraParams.id_token has the JSON Web Token
        // profile has all the information from the user
        req.session.id_token = 'ok';
        return done(null, profile, extraParams);
    });
passport.use(strategy);

// This can be used to keep a smaller payload
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user );
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});
```

Comment: Sounds like `session` does not exist on the request object. Are you following the Auth0 API correctly? Also, is that the full code in that file, or is there more to it? To be honest, I found it easier to implement Authentication using web tokens than using Auth0

Comment: Suggest you download the node.js quickstart and get that up and running first - https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nodejs  Takes about 2 mins - especially if you download the quickstart from your tenant so the clientId etc are already populated for you.